# Airflow opsGenie integration - alert header

Tags: airflow, opsgenie

We have an integration of Airflow alerts that are sent to opsGenie.
The alerts appear in opsGenie but the message subject says only "Airport aler:" and one needs to expand the alert to view the details.

In the Airflow code taskinstance.py Isee the following in def email_alert(self, exception):`default_subject = 'Airflow alert: {{ti}}'`
but it seems like the task_instance (ti) is not shown in opsGenie.

In regular emails of the same alert (in my GMail inbox) the message header does show the task instance details as well.

Comment: I don't understand why you are mixing between email settings to opsgenie. Are you sure you are using the Airflow opsGenie provider? Please share your code.

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain myself properly. The way we get Airflow alerts to opsGenie from Airflow is by sending an email to an address like 'my-team@my_company.opsgenie.net' and we get the alerts in the opsGenie UI.  I sent an email with the subject Testing 1,2,3 and in opsGenie UI the alert subject says only: 'Airflow alert:' - when I look at the alert in myinbox alert it has a subject like 'Opsgenie Alert: Testing: 1,2,3'.      In the opsGenie UI if we have an SLA the subject is also  displayed properly ([airflow] SLA miss on DAG=DAG_Name)

Comment: you are asking question about a custom code that you have. If you won't share the code we can't help you